# I am trying to code queue using stack. There is no error while I am running the code but the stack is not able to store the values

Tags: c, data-structures

I have initialised two stacks using a structure with which I am creating a queue. But the stack is not able to store the values which is why enqueue or dequeue operations are not working properly.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct stack{
    int top;
    int size;
    int *s;
};

int isfull(struct stack *st){
    if(st->top==st->size-1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isempty(struct stack *st){
    if(st->top==-1){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(struct stack *st,int x){
    if(isfull(st)){
        printf("FULL!!\n");
    }
    else{
        st->top++;
        st->s[st->top]=x;
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *st){
    int x=-1;
    if(isempty(st)){
        printf("EMPTY!!\n");
    }
    else{
        x=st->s[st->top];
        st->top--;
    }
    return x;
}

void enqueue(struct stack s1,int x){
    push(&s1,x);
}

int dequeue(struct stack s1,struct stack s2){
    int x=-1;
    if(isempty(&s2)){
        if(isempty(&s1)){
            printf("QUEUE IS EMPTY!!\n");
            return x;
        }
        else{
            while(!isempty(&s1)){
                push(&s2,pop(&s1));
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(&s2);
}

void display(struct stack st){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=st.top;i++){
        printf("%d",st.s[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n,choice;
    struct stack s1,s2;
    printf("ENTER SIZE OF QUEUE:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s1.size=n;
    s2.size=n;
    s1.top=-1;
    s2.top=-1;
    s1.s=(int *)malloc(s1.size*sizeof(int));
    s2.s=(int *)malloc(s2.size*sizeof(int));
    while(1){
        printf("1.ENQUEUE\n");
        printf("2.DEQUEUE\n");
        printf("3.DISPLAY\n");
        printf("4.EXIT\n");
        printf("ENTER YOUR CHOICE:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case(1):
                int x;
                printf("ENTER DATA:");
                scanf("%d",&x);
                enqueue(s1,x);
                break;
            case(2):
                int m;
                m=dequeue(s1,s2);
                printf("ELEMENT DELETED IS:%d\n",m);
                break;
            case(3):
                display(s2);
                break;
            case(4):
                exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the error? I think there might be an issue with passing the values to the function.

Comment: Hint: when you do `void f(int i) {i = 42;}   int main() {int x = 3; f(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` what do you think it will print?

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: *"I think there might be an issue with passing the values to the function."*: clearly. So make sure to pass pointers to what you want to get modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that the `enqueue` and `dequeue` don't take pointers as arguments, but `struct stack`. This means the function gets a *copy* of the given struct, and that the pointer you pass to `push` and `pop` (like `&s1`) is pointing to that local structure, not to the one in `main`. By consequence any update to the `top` member of that stack will not be seen by the caller.

I would suggest to:

- Consistently pass *pointers* to `struct` typed arguments. This was well done for the `push` and `pop` functions, and there is no reason why it should not be done the same way for `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions.
- Define a `struct queue` so that you abstract a bit that there are two stacks involved and don't have to pass both of them as argument to `dequeue`.
- Create separate functions for:

  - creating a new stack
  - displaying a stack
  - creating a new queue
  - displaying a queue
  - checking if a queue is empty

Here is how your code would then look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    int top;
    int size;
    int *s;
};

struct stack* newstack(int size) {
    struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->size = size;
    s->s = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    s->top = -1;
    return s;
}

int isfull(struct stack *st) {
    return st->top == st->size - 1;
}

int isempty(struct stack *st) {
    return st->top == -1;
}

void push(struct stack *st, int x) {
    if (isfull(st)){
        printf("Full!\n");
    } else {
        st->top++;
        st->s[st->top] = x;
    }
}

int pop(struct stack *st) {
    int x = -1;
    if (isempty(st)){
        printf("Empty!\n");
    } else {
        x = st->s[st->top];
        st->top--;
    }
    return x;
}

void displaystack(struct stack *st) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= st->top; i++) {
        printf("%d ", st->s[i]);
    }
}

struct queue {
    struct stack *s1;
    struct stack *s2;
};

struct queue* newqueue(int size) {
    struct queue *q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->s1 = newstack(size);
    q->s2 = newstack(size);
    return q;
}

int isemptyqueue(struct queue *q) {
    return isempty(q->s1) && isempty(q->s2);
}

void enqueue(struct queue *q, int x) {
    push(q->s1, x);
}

int dequeue(struct queue *q) {
    int x = -1;
    if (isemptyqueue(q)) {
        printf("Queue is empty!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (isempty(q->s2)) {
        while (!isempty(q->s1)) {
            push(q->s2, pop(q->s1));
        }
    }
    return pop(q->s2);
}

void displayqueue(struct queue *q) {
    displaystack(q->s1);
    printf("| ");
    displaystack(q->s2);
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    int n, choice, x, m;
    printf("Enter the size of the queue: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct queue *q = newqueue(n);
    while (choice != 4) {
        printf("1. Enqueue\n");
        printf("2. Dequeue\n");
        printf("3. Display\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter data: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            enqueue(q, x);
            break;
        case 2:
            m = dequeue(q);
            printf("The deleted element is: %d\n", m);
            break;
        case 3:
            displayqueue(q);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and for clearing up my concept on this. I knew where the error was but could not solve it.